# Version compatible method for joining strings

Tags: matlab

In older versions of MATLAB(e.g. 2015b), we can simply use

```
['aa','bb','cc']
```

to join 3 strings into one, `'aabbcc'`.

But in 2019b, I find the result of

```
["aa","bb","cc"]
```

would be

```
ans = 

  1×3 string array

    "aa"    "bb"    "cc"
```

, and it tells me I should use the `join` function to do the trick.

It seems a new feature, which is totally fine with me. However, when I found that I need to develop code in 2019b in my laptop, and our remote server uses 2015b, it comes to a disaster. I am wondering if there is some way to do the same job, i.e. get `"aabbcc"` in the example, and could be recognized by both 2015b & 2019b?

Comment: I have searched for online sources & documents for a while, but I don't have any luck to deal with it.

Comment: see related online help https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html

Comment: MATLAB `char` arrays (simple quote `['aa','bb','cc']`) still works the same in any version. They are indeed different than `strings` type (used with double quote: `["aa","bb","cc"]`). If you need something all version compatible, just use the `char` arrays as before, don't use the new data type which din't exist in earlier versions.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Thank you Thomas, your idea do work & fix my problem. But just change the double quotes into single ones seems easier for me actually. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between an array of chars `''` and a real string `""`. This explicit difference was introduced in [2017a](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html):

> string Arrays: Create string arrays using double quotes
>
> You can create strings using double quotes, just as you can create
>   character vectors with single quotes.
>
> ```
> str = "Hello, World" creates a string.
>
> str = ["Good" "morning"] creates a 1-by-2 string array.
> ```
>
> For more information, see Characters and Strings.

To get the same functionality as the well-known char arrays, you should substitute the concatenating `[]` with `strcat()` and to get the number of characters (independently whether it is a string or a char-array) by `strlen()` (because `length("Hello")` yields `1` but `strlen("Hello")` yields `5`).